# Stack Divider Not Showing in Card - Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am working on a card component in Chakra UI. The Stack Divider in the Card Body is not showing. Does it need to be formatted in a specific way to appear? For example, setting a certain width?

```js
<Card 
        width={"100%"}
        borderWidth="1px"
        borderRadius="lg" 
        marginX="auto" 
        paddingX={3} 
        maxWidth={"3xl"}>

        <CardHeader color="blue.500" size={"sm"} mt={3}>
            Citations {results.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults}
            <Divider orientation="horizontal" />
        </CardHeader>

        {results.items.map((result) => (
            <CardBody key={result.link} maxWidth="3xl">

                    <Stack divider={<StackDivider />} spacing='2'>
                        <Box>
                            <Link color='blue.500' href={result.link} isExternal>
                                {result.displayLink}<ExternalLinkIcon mx='4px' />
                            </Link>

                            <Link href={result.link}>
                                <Heading as='h2' size={'md'}>{result.title}</Heading>
                            </Link>

                            <Text noOfLines={3}>
                                {Parser(result.htmlSnippet)}
                            </Text>
                        </Box>
                    </Stack>
            </CardBody>
        ))}
</Card>
```

Here is an image of the Card Body:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it here:

```js
<Card 
            width={"100%"}
            borderWidth="1px"
            borderRadius="lg" 
            marginX="auto" 
            paddingX={3} 
            maxWidth={"3xl"}>

            <CardHeader color="blue.500" size={"sm"} mt={2}>
                Citations {results.searchInformation.formattedTotalResults}
                <Divider orientation="horizontal" />
            </CardHeader>

            <CardBody>
                <Stack divider={<StackDivider />} spacing='4' maxWidth="3xl">
                    {results.items.map((result) => (
                        
                            <Box key={result.link}>
                                <Link color='blue.500' href={result.link} isExternal>
                                    {result.displayLink}<ExternalLinkIcon mx='4px' />
                                </Link>

                                <Link href={result.link}>
                                    <Heading as='h2' size={'md'} mt={2} mb={2}>{result.title}</Heading>
                                </Link>

                                <Text noOfLines={3}>
                                    {Parser(result.htmlSnippet)}
                                </Text>
                            </Box>

                    ))}
                </Stack>
            </CardBody>
```